# How can I create custom IQ using smack

Tags: ejabberd, smack

I am creating a chat application using smack and ejabberd server. Most of the required features are implemented but the problem is I can't fetch the chat history between two users, after some research I have found that I need to implement `custom IQ` to achieve this. I have found a lot of similar question on SO, but none of this came to any help besides I smack api has changed a lot . Any sample code to implement this will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: Here you can find Openfire and Smack summary for custom IQ, so just ignore Openfire part https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37965356/mapping-openfire-custom-plugin-with-asmack-client/37972611#37972611

Comment: @MrPk thanks let me try