# Creating Custom Stanza in smack 4.2

Tags: android, xmpp, smack, multiuserchat

How can I sent a custom IQ Stanza using  smack 4.2  in android.
I tried to convert the following stanza in smack IQ but unsuccessful

```
<iq type="set" to="mygrp-2bf4a6cf@muclight.mydmain.org.com" from="+6500000000@mydmain.org.com" id="modarchive-22317496CE4C">
    <query
        xmlns="urn:xmpp:mam:1" queryid="queryId-1FF4671B-183F-4CEA-BF84-CAAA5BA3293A"/>  </iq>
```

My smack Code

```
 public IQ getCustomStanza(String group , String user){



        IQ miQ= new IQ ("query") {
            @Override
            protected IQChildElementXmlStringBuilder getIQChildElementBuilder(IQChildElementXmlStringBuilder xml) {

                return (IQChildElementXmlStringBuilder) xml.append ("<query xmlns= urn:xmpp:mam:1 queryid=queryId-1FF4671B-183F-4CEA-BF84-CAAA5BA3293A/>");

            }
        };
        try {
            miQ.setFrom (JidCreate.bareFrom (user));
            miQ.setType (IQ.Type.set);
            miQ.setTo (JidCreate.bareFrom (group));
            miQ.setStanzaId ();
        } catch (XmppStringprepException e) {
            e.printStackTrace ( );
        }
        return miQ;
    }
```

but getting null

Comment: Hi did you find solution?

Answer (score 0):

Check out how this guy structured his [class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41362617/8587899).... try to reverse engineer it to suite your needs