# How to add feature to xmpp server?

Tags: java, xmpp, chat, openfire

I want to add voting feature to my chat app, am I need to add it to server side (openfire is my preference) or client side? And can you suggest any material to study xmpp and how it work?
Thanks

Comment: General: http://xmpp.org/extensions/index.html - Openfire: https://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/documentation.jsp. For votes: look xep-0004 (if you use SMACK API: http://download.igniterealtime.org/smack/docs/latest/documentation/extensions/dataforms.html). If you need to add feature to Openfire, you have to look for custom plugin (http://download.igniterealtime.org/openfire/docs/latest/documentation/plugin-dev-guide.html and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37965356/mapping-openfire-custom-plugin-with-asmack-client/37972611#37972611)

Comment: Thanks, i will check it